# What's the right way to construct a class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a class with a lot of non null fields,and nullable ones. If I declare them like

```
val key : String
```

the Kotlin compiler will of course give me an error telling me they need to be initialized, so I figured I should put the not nullable ones in a constructor, and add a secondary constructor for when I need the nullable fields initialized with non null values. This is to avoid calling a constructor and then setters, I'd then call one constructor instead. This is what it came out looking like

```
import utilities.Constants
import java.util.*

class Action(val key: String,
        //val actionNode: ActionNode
             val date: Date,
             val stringValue: String,
             val autoRecognitionStatus: Constants.MeasurementAutoRecognized,
             val recognitionId: String,
             val method: Constants.MeasurementMethod,
             val userKey: String,
             val userName: String,
             val isInRange: Boolean) {


    var pictureUrl: String? = null
    var remotePictureUrl: String? = null



    constructor(key: String,
            // actionNode: ActionNode
                date: Date,
                stringValue: String,
                autoRecognitionStatus: Constants.MeasurementAutoRecognized,
                recognitionId: String,
                method: Constants.MeasurementMethod,
                userKey: String,
                userName: String,
                isInRange: Boolean,
                pictureUrl: String?,
                remotePictureUrl: String?)
            : this(key,
            // actionNode
            date,
            stringValue,
            autoRecognitionStatus,
            recognitionId,
            method,
            userKey,
            userName,
            isInRange) {
        this.pictureUrl = pictureUrl
        this.remotePictureUrl = remotePictureUrl

    }

}
```

My problem is that this code just looks horrible. I'm not saying that the looks is what matters the most, but I have a feeling this a wrong way to do it cause of that. Especially cause I'm having to re-write a ton of parameters when I need to delegate to the primary constructor

Is there a better, or "right" way to do this?

EDIT: What I'm asking: Did I write a lot of code for something that can be done a lot easier with Kotlin?

Comment: Define "better" and "right".

Comment: @Krythic My problem with kotlin is that you can do almost the same thing in multiple ways. Lateinit, by Delegate , etc ... What I'm asking: Is the way I wrote the class wrong? It would probably work, but did I write a wall of code for something that Kotlin might do in much less?

Comment: kotlin have default getter and setter then what purpose you used constructor here?

Comment: @sasikumar This is a refactor of old java code. My team is used to constructing this class in one line passing everything in a constructor, rather than constructing an empty class then use setters, and it makes sense in our app because all the data is available at time of constructing the class.

Comment: Observation: This data structure looks pretty big. Is all of this data required? If so, is there a way related fields can be grouped together into their own types? (e.g. combine `userKey` and `userName` into a single type)

Comment: @byxor totally right, but it's a project that's been made like that for a long time. And sometimes you have to stay conform with what your team is used to, and introduce subtle changes rather than changing everything.

Comment: @vlatkozelka Understood. I once made a pull request that fixed whitespace in ~30 files that many other developers depended on. Reviewers weren't so happy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the class is complete like this, you can make it a *data class* as well. Also *Kotlin* supports default values for properties, so you only need one constructor, the primary one. The following class *looks* nicer and is almost identical to what you defined.

```
data class Action(
     val key: String,
     val date: Date,
     val stringValue: String,
     val autoRecognitionStatus: MeasurementAutoRecognized,
     val recognitionId: String,
     val method: MeasurementMethod,
     val userKey: String,
     val userName: String,
     val isInRange: Boolean,
     var pictureUrl: String? = null,
     var remotePictureUrl: String? = null
)
```

If you need the secondary constructor for *Java*, you can annotate the given constructor with [`@JvmOverloads`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-overloads/).

Comment: I still need to put to other methods in there, and I don't think this is just a data class. I suppose what I was missing is that I could've declared the 2 optional vars in the primary constructor, instead of adding a secondary constructor just for those.

Comment: The _data class_ will give you default implementations for comparison and to string conversion. Everything else you need to implement, you'd just add within the body of the class.